# I want to use jersey client in my code I have imported the packages still it shows error

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to use jersey client in my code. I have imported the packages still and it shows an error.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

I am using JDev environment.

Despite that when I run my code it throws:

```
Error(3,33):  package com.sun.jersey.api.client does not exist
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

Any suggestion why is it throwing the error ?

Comment: Have you added the library to the classpath?

Comment: No , How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to download the library e.g. [from here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). Afterwards you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.oracledistilled.com/java/adding-java-libraries-to-oracle-jdeveloper-11g-r1/) to add the library to your project. Jersey depends also on other libraries (included in the bundle), so make sure to add them as well.